# Elixir GenServer.start_link throws exception instead of returning a tuple

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I'm playing a bit with [`GenServer`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html) and I have problem implementing custom `init` callback.

Please consider following code:

```
defmodule GenS do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(initial \\ 0) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, initial)
  end

  def init(initial) do
    case initial do
      3 -> {:stop, "Can't initialise with 3"}
      _ -> {:ok, initial}
    end
  end
end

case GenS.start_link(3) do
  {:error, reason} -> IO.puts "Failed with #{reason}"
  {:ok,    _}      -> IO.puts "This has worked!"
end

IO.puts "I'm still alive!"
```

When executing this code I can see the output:

```
▶ elixir gens.ex
** (EXIT from #PID<0.46.0>) "Can't initialise with 3"
```

While I was expecting similar output for *successful* branch (when value different than `3` passed as an argument):

```
▶ elixir gens.ex
This has worked!
I'm still alive!
```

According to the documentation of [`GenServer.start_link/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html#start_link/3):

> If the `init/1` callback fails with reason, this function returns `{:error, reason}`. Otherwise, if it returns `{:stop, reason}` or `:ignore`, the process is terminated and this function returns `{:error, reason}` or `:ignore`, respectively.

I'd expect the tuple to be returned, agains which I could patter match, but it seems not to be the case. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd expect the tuple to be returned, agains which I could patter match, but it seems not to be the case. Do you have any advice?

The problem here is that you're linking the to the spawned process and returning `{:stop, ...}` from `init` is sending an exit signal to the calling process, which by default kills the calling process.

You can either switch to using `GenServer.start` (and manually linking the processes later if you wish), or trapping exit signals by running the following before starting `GenS`:

```
Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
```

<sub>(Note that this will send a message to the calling process when `GenS` dies which you may want to discard to prevent wasting memory.)</sub>

In both cases I get the following output:

```
Failed with Can't initialise with 3
I'm still alive!
```

Comment: That's very interesting. Thanks for sharing this. It turns that the documentation sounds confusing - based on which I'd expect result something I can safely match against...